Error During Installing SAP NetWeaver 7.52
I want to install "SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP Developer Edition 7.52 SP04" on openSUSE 15.6, and this error appears:

Abort execution because of Step returns modlib.jslib.caughtException

ASE license file will expire March 31, 2025.
Is there any solution for problem?
Uploaded last installation log
SAPCAR: 15 file(s) extracted
SAPCAR: rc 0 
=>sapparam(1c): No Profile used.
=>sapparam: SAPSYSTEMNAME neither in Profile nor in Commandline
################################################
Abort execution because of 
Step returns modlib.jslib.caughtException
################################################

Error: sapinst has finished with an error code, please find logs in /tmp/sapinst_instdir
Error code: 20


SP what number? Which precise product did you install, the ABAP trial, which database? The most frequent reason is a Sybase license problem, so make sure to install the latest one in the right directory (this link may help you).

i checked the ase license file it'll expire March 31 2025 and i want to install "SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP Developer Edition 7.52 SP04" on opensuse 15.6

If you have pasted the license file in the right directory, then the issue could be that Sybase cannot work with openSUSE above 15.3. Either install the version 15.3 or try this link.

SAP ASE dataserver executable version 16.0 SP04 PL05 or lower cannot be executed on a Linux system with GLIBC 2.36 and higher. See the SAP note 3425215 - SYB: dataserver fails to execute on Linux with GLIBC 2.36 and higher for more information (the access requires an SAP license).
The ABAP trial 7.52 SP04 comes with ASE 16.0.03.06.
OpenSUSE Leap 15.3 comes with GLIBC 2.31.
Run ldd --version to know the GLIBC version which comes with your OpenSUSE version.
Note that the below errors may also come from an invalid ASE license (see here how to install it):

=>sapparam(1c): No Profile used.
=>sapparam: SAPSYSTEMNAME neither in Profile nor in Commandline

